# Error when running emacs make install on remote machine

Tags: linux, emacs, ssh

I am trying to install emacs on a machine that I'm accessing through ssh.
I downloaded the emacs-24.5.tar.gz which I transferred to the root directory of my remote machine.

I ran the ./configure command and then navigated to the emacs-24.5 folder and ran the make install command

I unfortunately ran into this error

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/icons': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/emacs.png': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-etc] Error 1
```

How do I get emacs working on the remote machine now?

Comment: you running that as root? you can't write into that dir unless you're root.

Comment: Sounds the same as this [super user post](http://superuser.com/questions/637979/install-emacs-without-sudo)

Answer (score 1):

Your description of what steps you took make it a little difficult to know if you missed anything. For example, I'm assuming you ran tar on the tarball  before you ran configure or make? Also, little concerned when you say you ran configure and THEN navigated to the 24.5 directory? You should be running make install from the same directory/folder where you ran configure. You also didn't indicate you had run make bootstrap.

The steps should be

- scp emacs-24.5.tar.gz user@remote-host:~
- ssh user@remote-host
- tar xzf emacs-24.5.tar.gz
- cd emacs-24.5
- ./configure
- make bootstrap
- sudo make install
- Notice in the output from the make install there are directions on an additional command you need to run to set movemail permissions. This command also needs to be run under sudo

I'm assuming your not ssh'ing intot the remote host as root as this would be a bad practice. This means that when you do the make install, you need to run the process with root privileges, so you need to use sudo.

You should also check the output from configure and make sure there are no errors. Configure will also list emacs features which are turned on/off depending on whether you have various supporting libraries installed. If you scroll the terminal output from configure up a couple of pages, you will see the printout. If there are features listed with a 'no' which you want/expect, you will need to go through the documentation and work out which additional supporting libraries you need. However, most of the time, with modern linux distros setup for desktop use, everything will likely already be there. Might be different on a server and I can't speak about Windows and what it might require.